# PHP I18N gettext not translating one specific string in a specific language

Tags: php, html, internationalization, gettext

Ive been wrecking my brain and searching the internet for a while now without finding a solution (or case) similar to mine, so Im turning to everyone here:

I'm currently working on a website that uses the gettext-extension for internationalization, currently its only planned to be used in english and german.
All said and done, I have the translation working for the most part, but there is one to me very odd problem that I just cannot seem to solve:

First, some code/background:

The problem occurs in a footer which is included via php and the footer contains a small side-navigation:

```
<div class="nav fixed-bottom style-footer">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./index.php?page=contact"><?php echo _("btn_contact"); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><?php echo _("btn_language"); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><?php echo _("btn_contact"); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

(the "btn_language" was added by my as a test, thinking that it may be the case that the entire file cant be translated properly, but thats not the case), also the page is build with a banner.php, nav.php, content.php, footer.php where the content.php dynamically changes/shows the content, the remaining parts are always displayed/"static" and fixed to their positions (Header above Nav above content above footer (fixed to bottom of the browser-window))

the po-files were originally created via PoEdit, it correctly recognized and grabbed the "btn_contact" entry among all the others, the po-Entry in question looks like this:

german:

```
#: includes/footer.php:3
msgid "btn_contact"
msgstr "Kontakt"
```

english:

```
#: includes/footer.php:3
msgid "btn_contact"
msgstr "Contact"
```

Now, when I open the page, every string is displayed correctly, *aside* from the btn_contact one, even the btn_language coming from the same file (footer.php) and this *only* occurs in german, when I switch to english it correctly shows "Contact", instead of "btn_contact" like it does when switching to german (if its unclear, Ill add two pics showing the english and german at the bottom)

I am developing locally on my Windows 10 PC, using IIS to host the page on my PC while working on it, it's the same on my coworkers Windows 10 PC and his MacBook (both hosting using XAMPP)

I have tried deleting the btn_contact-Entry in the po file, I deleted and recreated the german translation via PoEdit, clearing browser cache (it happens in Chrome, Edge (aka reskinned Chrome) and Firefox, all up-to-date) etc, deleting and rewriting the lines in the footer.php, deleting and reinstalling IIS

I dont know what else I can change (inb4 its one supereasy change that my dumbass just isnt seeing atm)

Should I have just missed a solution for this problem due to weak Google-Fu, I apologize

Should other code-parts be needed for clarification I'll add them when needed

[The part of the page in question, both languages compared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXzqU.png)

Comment: Have you tried replacing the German file with the English one and see if that one works for you as well? That way you can deduct that it's not something in the file itself that is breaking. If that works, I would change the value of btn_contact and see if that holds up. If that works, check which character encoding you're using. Let me know the results, and I'll help you debug this further.

Comment: I tried changing the values, which oddly enough did display the then correct term for btn_contact, but when I changed back to "Kontakt" it stayed at the test-entry. I then tried switching the files, which seemed to entirely break everything. In a fit of rage I then deleted the entire language directory (root/locales/locale code/LC_MESSAGES/main.po) and redid it entirely from scratch, and it seems to work for some reason (for now)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not translated from `.po` files but from `.mo` files.  You can create the `.mo` file from a `.po` file with the `msgfmt` program.

It looks like your German `.mo` file is incomplete and is missing the translation for "btn_contact".  You can check the contents of your `.mo` file with the program `msgunfmt`:

```
msgunfmt FILENAME.mo
```

See the docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) for more details on the translation workflow. After you have updated (recompiled) the `.mo` file, the translation should appear.

By the way, there is no need to use ugly symbolic identifiers like "btn_contact" as message ids. Just use the original strings:

```
_("Contact")
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and the guilty was in fact the .mo file ... or the .po, depend of the point of view.

The .po file was containing a lot of `fuzzy` translations and the .mo file was compiled without them as, by default, `msgfmt` excludes `fuzzy` messages from the compiled catalog.

So the fix for me was to recompile the .mo with the fuzzy strings.

`msgfmt --use-fuzzy -o my.mo my.po`

And don't forget to restart php-fpm (or Apache) after any change to the mo file as it is cached by the system.